# Foreign Key from an existing database with Persistent Haskell

Tags: sql, haskell, persistent

I am currently working on a project using Haskell and Persistent and I run in a small issue. I want to code a little library to deal with a generic approach for authentication where each user gets an "identity".

This identity is stored in a database using persistent.

```
Identity
  lastSeen       UTCTime
  registration   UTCTime
  karma          Int DEFAULT=0
  banned         UTCTime Maybe
```

My idea is that the users of my lib can add map their account datatype to an identity. My issue is that, when I give the type `IdentityId` to a field of my user datatype, the column is an integer (that's fine) but the references constraint is missing.

For instance :

```
User
  email          Text
  identity       IdentityId
  UniqueIdentity identity
```

I get:

```
Migrating: CREATE TABLE "identity"("id" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,"last_seen" TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,"registration" TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,"karma" INTEGER NOT NULL,"banned" TIMESTAMP NULL)
Migrating: CREATE TABLE "user"("id" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,"email" VARCHAR NOT NULL,"identity" INTEGER NOT NULL,CONSTRAINT "unique_identity" UNIQUE ("identity"))
```

The trick is: the definition of user is done in a different file and I suppose the issue is here.

Can I do something to force persistent to add a references constraint?

Thank you by advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming that you are using SQLite. SQLite supports foreign key constraints, but by default, they are not turned on. You must turn them on before the migration.

[SQLite Foreign Key Support: 2. Enabling Foreign Key Support](https://www.sqlite.org/foreignkeys.html#fk_enable)

This is the SQLite command to turn them on:

```
PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON;
```

You can turn this PRAGMA on via Haskell and Persistent with the following code:

```
import qualified Database.Sqlite as Sqlite
import Database.Persist.Sqlite (createSqlPool, wrapConnection)

enableForeignKeys :: Sqlite.Connection -> IO ()
enableForeignKeys conn = Sqlite.prepare conn "PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON;" >>= void . Sqlite.step

createSqliteBackend :: Text -> LogFunc -> IO SqlBackend
createSqliteBackend connStr logFunc = do
  conn <- Sqlite.open connStr
  enableForeignKeys conn
  wrapConnection conn logFunc
```

`createSqliteBackend` will return an `SqlBackend` that run Persistent queries against with the `foreign_keys` Pragma turned on.

[Yesod Cookbook: Activate foreign key checking in Sqlite](https://github.com/yesodweb/yesod-cookbook/blob/master/cookbook/Activate-foreign-key-checking-in-Sqlite.md)